# Why does my automated build run so slowly inside a Docker container?

Tags: c, linux, docker, continuous-integration

I am currently working on an automated build/CI system for various embedded firmware projects which have been developed in Rowley Associates CrossStudio. The projects can each be built at the command line using CrossBuild.

Now, on to the Docker part:

We need a way of guaranteeing consistent build environments. A build must run identically on any engineer workstation *or* the build server. As all of the build steps, including running CrossBuild can be executed in a command line Linux environment, I opted to use Docker containers to guarantee environmental consistency.

My intention is to use Docker containers as disposable 'build bots' in the following way. When a build is initiated (either manually by the engineer or by an automated build process), a container is created from the appropriate image, the process runs to completion, outputs are copied to persistent storage and then the container is thrown away.

At the moment, I'm in the process of walking through the build steps manually to prove that everything works as I expected. It doesn't!

I have a Docker container with the appropriate tools installed and can manually invoke CrossBuild and successfully build my project. Unfortunately, the build takes about 30 minutes to complete. This compares to a build time of ~1.5 minutes if I use the same tool directly on my Windows workstation.

I have a Windows 7 (x64) workstation and so to run the Docker container, I'm using Boot2Docker on VirtualBox.

If I observe the CPU and memory usage of the Docker container (either by running ps -aux inside the Boot2Docker VM or observing the resource usage of the Boot2Docker VM in Windows Task Manager), barely any resources are being used (<5% CPU usage, tens of megabytes of RAM). If I build the project using CrossBuild directly on Windows, the CPU usage fluctuates but peaks at 25% (i.e. maxing out one of my 4 threads).

I have proved that, in principle, processes inside the Docker container can occupy all available CPU resources by writing a simple infinite loop in Python, running it and observing CPU usage in Task Manager on the host PC. As expected, a single core was fully utilised.

**Further information**

- Behind the scenes, CrossBuild is driving GCC-ARM
- In order to get data in to and out of the Docker container, I'm using VirtualBox shared folders and then creating the container using the -v argument for each share.

**Current lines of enquiry**

I just had a moment of inspiration and started to wonder whether there might be a read/write bandwidth constraint caused by the way that I'm getting data in and out of the container (i.e. the CPU is never being fully utilised as most of the time is spent waiting for reads and writes). I will investigate this possibility.

Comment: I the output of `top` run inside the container may help narrow down the issue. Without more details, any answers would be guesses/speculation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39166630/596285) for some possible causes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions BMitch. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing drives from Windows to VirtualBox is notoriously slow. If you want to build from your local machine, use [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) instead. If you want to replicate a cloud CI environment, you create a volume

```
docker volume create --name mydata
```

upload data to it

```
docker run -v mydata:/data --name temp alpine top
docker cp /my/local/dir temp:/data
docker rm -f temp
```

Then mount that docker volume as needed in your other CI container (that step can be included in the above).

Note that for a real CI, your data could come from other sources like github. In that case, you can create a container just to download the data into the docker volume.

Comment: Thanks Alkaline. Unfortunately I'm limited to using Windows 7 and so Docker for Windows is out.